# types as mold to delegated classes in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types

I am working in [ScalaFX](http://code.google.com/p/scalafx/) Project. In this moment I am adapting classes from `javafx.scene.control.cell`. In this package, methods with same signature are duplicated in many classes. e.g. [`StringConverter<T>  converter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxListCell.html#converterProperty). To avoid unnecessary duplication of code (and to know how to use existential types), I created the following code:

```
// Defined in scalafx.util package. All classes in scalafx use this trait
package scalafx.util

trait SFXDelegate[+D <: Object] extends AnyRef {
  def delegate: D

  override def toString = "[SFX]" + delegate.toString

  override def equals(ref: Any): Boolean = {
    ref match {
      case sfxd: SFXDelegate[_] => delegate.equals(sfxd.delegate)
      case _ => delegate.equals(ref)
    }
  }

  override def hashCode = delegate.hashCode
}

// Package Object
package scalafx.scene.control

import javafx.{ util => jfxu }
import javafx.beans.{ property => jfxbp }
import javafx.scene.{ control => jfxsc }
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty
import scalafx.util.SFXDelegate
import scalafx.util.StringConverter

package object cell {

  type Convertable[T] = {
    def converterProperty: jfxbp.ObjectProperty[jfxu.StringConverter[T]]
  }

  type JfxConvertableCell[T] = jfxsc.Cell[T] with Convertable[T]

  trait ConvertableCell[C <: JfxConvertableCell[T], T]
    extends SFXDelegate[C] {
    def converter: ObjectProperty[StringConverter[T]] = ObjectProperty(delegate.converterProperty.getValue)
    def converter_=(v: StringConverter[T]) {
      converter() = v
    }
  }

}
```

In `JfxConvertableCell` type I wanna say

> My type is a `javafx.scene.control.Cell` of type `T` that has a method called `converterProperty` that returns a `javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty` of type `javafx.util.StringConverter[T]`.

While in `ConvertableCell` trait, my intention is say that delegate value (from `SFXDelegate` trait) must be of type `JfxConvertableCell`. The first class that I tried to create was the counter-part of `CheckBoxListCell`:

```
package scalafx.scene.control.cell

import javafx.scene.control.{cell => jfxscc}
import scalafx.scene.control.ListCell
import scalafx.util.SFXDelegate

class CheckBoxListCell[T](override val delegate: jfxscc.CheckBoxListCell[T] = new jfxscc.CheckBoxListCell[T])
  extends ListCell[T](delegate)
  with ConvertableCell[jfxscc.CheckBoxListCell[T], T]
  with SFXDelegate[jfxscc.CheckBoxListCell[T]] {

}
```

However in this moment I got this message from compiler:

> type arguments [javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxListCell[T],T] do not conform to trait ConvertableCell's type parameter bounds [C <: scalafx.scene.control.cell.package.JfxConvertableCell[T],T]

Did I understand something wrong? `CheckBoxListCell` have the `converterProperty` method. Can't we use types and existential types as a mold into which we fit our delegated classes?

Comment: i am not shure why it does not work.
cant you work with some implicit conversions which cast to the type you want to get?
https://gist.github.com/257758

Comment: Probably the relation CheckBoxListCell <: JfxConvertableCell is not true because the compiler is not smart enough to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your definition of `converterProperty`. You define it as a parameterless method, while it is seen by scala as a method with an empty parameter list.
Just doing this makes it compile properly:

```
type Convertable[T] = {
  def converterProperty(): jfxbp.ObjectProperty[jfxu.StringConverter[T]]
}
```

While scala treats a parameterless method and a method with an empty parameter list as essentially the same thing as far as overriding is concerned (see scala spec @ 5.1.4), they are still different entites. 
And when interroperating with java code (which has no notion of parameterless method), a nullary method is seen as a method with an empty prameter list, not as a parameterless method, thus the structural types don't match.